# How to create an image from a container after executing a command to run a server in that container?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a running container named nodeserver1. I issued the following command to actually run the node server
`docker exec -d nodeserver1 nodejs ipshow.js`
Now how do I create an image from nodeserver1 such that the next time I build a container from this image, I do not need to issue the exec command.
I have tried to commit it using `docker commit <container id> <some-new-name>` but when I run the new container, it doesn't start the node server.

Answer (score 1):

You probably would like to use the multistage build: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/

Here's an example shamelessy copied from the docker documentation:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Probably this is a better example using named builds:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go    .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Here, the key is `COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .`. Notice how it uses `--from=builder` to fetch the artifact from the other image.

Comment: +1. The key is the CMD command at the end of the build file. Just committing the docker container doesn't tell docker to run any files when the container starts, that has to be part of the build file or part of start instructions for docker (exec) or docker compose.

Comment: @ChrisMitchell: I might have misunderstood what you mean, but I think you meant the COPY command before the CMD. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: No the CMD command. Its the instruction that tells docker what to run when the container starts. See here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd